# Colab TPU error InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device for operation

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, tpu, google-cloud-tpu

in google colab when using TPU , i have the following error

InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device for operation Adam/iterations/IsInitialized/VarIsInitializedOp: {{node Adam/iterations/IsInitialized/VarIsInitializedOp}} was explicitly assigned to /job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:0 but available devices are [ /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0, /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0 ]. Make sure the device specification refers to a valid device.
     [[Adam/iterations/IsInitialized/VarIsInitializedOp]]

```
TPU_WORKER = 'grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR']
        resolver = tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(TPU_WORKER)
        tf.contrib.distribute.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
        strategy = tf.contrib.distribute.TPUStrategy(resolver)
        with strategy.scope():
            # Setup the model inputs / outputs
            model = Model(inputs=[inputs_img, inputs_mask], outputs=outputs)
            # Compile the model
            model.compile(
                optimizer = Adam(lr=lr),
                loss=self.loss_total(inputs_mask)
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving from `keras.models` and `keras.layers` to `tf.keras.models` and `tf.keras.layers` solved the issue for me.
Also make sure that you are not using local storage. Use GCS buckets instead.

Comment: Hi! when I try doing this I get a "ModuleNotFoundError ". How can I fix this? I am also working on a colab notebook. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reference TPU colab, make sure to change accelerator to a TPU:
runtime -> change run time -> TPU

https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/tpu.ipynb